# Blender IK armature rotation issue importing animation to Unity

Tags: animation, import, unity, .fbx

I was making some animations and discovered strange artifacts when importing certain rotations to unity. When main body rotates while IK limbs move on their own, Unity seems to not compute correctly the positions of the baked animation, so the whole body seems to vibrate, moving the limbs in a completely wrong way. I attach the difference between the two animation tests I was doing for realizing when did this issue appeared.

I attach a link to the blender animation:
https://media.giphy.com/media/f6K0jitr4erEocGDZo/giphy.gif
and a link to the animation imported to Unity:
https://media.giphy.com/media/H62Vu0MDaAWqFej4JE/giphy.gif
[image: Armature setup][image: Export settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should apply your rotation and scale, by pressing ctrl A.

Comment: Yes! thats definitely something to do, but was not the cause of the whole armature vibrating. I also tried changing rotation from quaternion to Euler, and combining the whole mesh into one only piece. Nothing of that worked, so I just kept playing around with the export settings

Answer (score 0):

After some very random ideas of changing angles to euler, playing around with unity import settings, and making some variations in the armature structure, I found a solution: unchecking export "only deform bones" made it for some reason. Then I realized that the body (main central bone) was not set as a deform bone, and that the mesh was just parented to it. I hope someone finds it also helpful ;)